# Mocking method before activity is created?

Tags: android, mockito, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I am using Espresso and Mockito for testing an Activity. Is it possible to mock a method before an activity is created.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    callSomeMethod();
    callAnotherMethod();
}

protected void callSomeMethod() {
    //do some work
}

protected void callAnotherMethod() {
    //do some work
}

}
```

My test class looks like

```
public class ActivityTest{
@Rule
public MyActivityRule testRule = new MyActivityRule(MyActivity.class);

public void test_preconditions(){
assertNotNull(testRule.getActivity())
}
}
```

But i need to mock callSomeMethod() and callAnotherMethod() method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what is `MyActivityRule`?

Comment: As the straightforward solution, I would create TestMyActivity and override methods that I need. Or I would write own rule which will launch spied activity instead of normal one

Comment: I was trying to see if I could do something in beforeActivityLaunched () method but no luck. 

public class MyActivityRule extends ActivityTestRule<MyActivityRule> {

    public MyActivity myActivity;

    public MyActivityRule(Class<MyActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
    // do something here    
    }
}